# Post multiple entries via Channel Form?

Tags: channel-entries

Don't need an edit function - just a way for a new member to post new entries, one time, in custom fields (10 of them) in a single channel via one page Channel Form. So basically one form with 10 fields, each of which will be a new entry in one single channel.

Not sure if Channel Form can do this or if there's another plugin. I found one called [Mefu](http://www.eevolution.co.nz/index.php?/products/mefu) but it only works for editing multiples not posting new ones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should this be done through the frontend or backend (CP)?

Comment: Tim...is front end via Channel Form

Comment: I once built an extension called Bankcracker to do this. (Well, actually it allows you to post entries to multiple channels in a single submission, but the principle is the same). Unfortunately I've not had a chance to update it since Safecracker became Channel Form, so it probably won't work with the latest version of EE, but you might be able to use it as the basis for building your own add-on: https://github.com/thisisjamessmith/Bankcracker

Answer (score 2):

The [Channel Form module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html) is what you use to submit entries from the front-end of the site.

> The Channel Form **makes it possible to add** and edit entries from
>   outside of the Control Panel using a regular form inside a template.

I don't understanding the "multiple entries" part of your question title so can't offer much assistance there.

Comment: Basically one Channel Form page/template with 10 fields. Each of these fields is a custom field which instead of posting to one entry with 10 custom fields it posts one custom field (with different content) to 10 entries in the same channel.

Comment: I can't get my head around that but try 10 Channel Form tags and submit them one right after another with ajax.

Comment: I think Anna_MediaGirl is right about sending them with ajax!

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm on to a different non-Ajax solution with help from someone on the EE forums. Thanks for your time on this one. Seems it is doable but not completed yet.

Comment: When you have it working, please take a moment to add the solution here as an answer to complete the SE process.

Comment: @segovius did you manage to get this working. Have a similar requirement where when I update a date field on one entry, I need that date to be populated onto another set of specific entries in the same channel.

Comment: In the mean time (2,5 years), is there a way to post to multiple channel entries at once, via 1 form, via the front end?